# Howto redirect from axios interceptor in reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux, axios

I am trying to check each axios request for presence of token inside the header for non-public paths. I want to take the user to login page in case token is not found.
But this is inside reactjs app. What is the way to make this happen?

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
 //If the header does not contain the token and the url not public, redirect to login  
 var accessToken = null;
 if(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserString')){
  accessToken =  'bearer '+JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserString')).tokenDetails.accessToken;
 }

 var configURL = config.url;
 //if token is found add it to the header
 if (accessToken) {
   if (config.method !== 'OPTIONS') {
          config.headers.authorization = accessToken;
   }
 }
 //otherwise if the request is not for login page/auth service/home redirect to login page
 else if(!isNotOpenPath(config.url)){

   //we may want to store current path in the cookies. This can be retrieved after login is successful
   //WHAT TO DO HERE TO TAKE USER TO LOGIN PAGE IN THE REACT JS APP????
  }    
}
```

How to signal react app, particularly we don't have dispatch here.
Can I just use 
`document.location.href='\login'`?

Comment: Why not window.location = 'loginPath' ?

Comment: Ok. But that would  be the approach. right? No reactjs specific way exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to have routes inside your app is using React Router...
Then to navigate you could try this...

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

Comment: browserHistory makes sense and works well too :) thanks!